# could not toggle when same icon is clicked twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have 3 icon where user gets to select and they can select multiple icons but if the same icon is clicked it should toggle. I mean when i click on facebook icon and twitter icon both icon should be highlighted but if i click facebook or twitter icon again then it should not be highlighted. Highlighting is working but clicking twice does not remove the highlight.

Here is my code

```
const socialPlatforms = [
{ name: 'facebook', fontName: 'facebook-square', icon: 'facebook-icon' },
{ name: 'twitter', fontName: 'twitter-square', icon: 'twitter-icon' },
{ name: 'instagram', fontName: 'instagram', icon: 'instagram-icon' },
];

addPlatform = (platform) => {
this.props.selectPlatform(platform);
};


render() {
const { settings } = this.props;
console.log('settings', settings.platforms);
const socialPlatform = socialPlatforms.map((platform, index) =>
  <FontAwesome
    name={platform.fontName}
    key={index}
    className={`icon-pointer font-awesome-icons ${settings.platforms.indexOf(platform.name) === -1 ? '' : platform.icon}`}
    size="5x"
    onClick={() => { this.addPlatform(platform.name); }}
  />
);


export const addPlatform = (platform) => ({
  type: ADD_PLATFORM,
  platform,
});

const initialState = {
loading: false,
platforms: [],
};

export default(state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case ADD_PLATFORM: {
    let index = state.platforms.indexOf(action.platform);
    if (index === -1) {
      return {
        ...state,
        platforms: [...state.platforms, action.platform],
      };
    }
    return {
      ...state,
      platforms: state.platforms.filter((localIndex) => localIndex !== index),
    };
  }
  default:
    return state;
}
};
```

I have used filter for toggling and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

`localIndex` should be the second argument of the [filter callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control). You are using the first one which is element.